# Получить GIT_BRANCH переменную в связке Android - Gradle - Jenkins

Tags: android, gradle, jenkins, android-gradle

При при выполнении gradle-задачи по сборке Android приложения мне необходимо знать с какой ветки выполняется сборка.

Для этого я в build.gradle написал следующий код:

```
def gitBranch() {
    def branch = ""
    def proc = "git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD".execute()
    proc.in.eachLine { line -> branch = line }
    proc.err.eachLine { line -> println line }
    proc.waitFor()
    branch
}
```

При выполнении сборки у себя на компьютере я вижу, что ветка определяется верно. Например - **staging**.

При выполнении этой же задачи на Jenkins я всегда получаю в ответе только HEAD. На англоязычном стэкоферлоу пишут, что для Дженкинса необходимо использовать переменную `$GIT_BRANCH`.

Действительно, если я в консоли Дженкинса перед выполнением задачи ставлю команду `echo $GIT_BRANCH | cut -d / -f 2` я вижу, что выводится сообщение с правильной веткой (**staging**), но добавление этого же кода в gradle приводит к ошибкам компиляции и у меня на компьютере и на Дженкинсе.

Вот *неверный* код:

```
def gitBranch() {
    def branch = ""
    def proc = "echo $GIT_BRANCH | cut -d / -f 2".execute()
    proc.in.eachLine { line -> branch = line }
    proc.err.eachLine { line -> println line }
    proc.waitFor()
    branch
}
```

Вопрос: уважаемые коллеги, как правильно получить название Git-ветки на Дженкинс, используя для этого задачи gradle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Ответ на вопрос получен в чате телеграмм [Android Developers](https://t.me/android_ru). Дублирую сюда, возможно, это окажется ещё кому-нибудь полезным.

============

Для того, чтобы корректно обрабатывать ситуацию в работе и на компьютере и на Jenkins, метод `gitBranch` необходимо привести к следующему виду:

```
def static gitBranch() {
    // тут мы получаем системную переменную Jenkins
    def branch = System.getenv("GIT_BRANCH")

    // если она не пустая, значит мы работаем на CI и наш текущий адрес
    // ветки выглядит примерно как origin/MY_GIT_BRANCH
    // нам надо взять только имя MY_GIT_BRANCH
    if (branch != null) {
        def (origin, path) = branch.split("/")
        branch = path
    }

    // если переменная пустая, значит мы работаем локально, поэтому получаем имя
    // локальной ветки
    if (branch == null) {
        def proc = "git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD".execute()
        proc.in.eachLine { line -> branch = line }
        proc.err.eachLine { line -> println line }
        proc.waitFor()
    }

    branch
}
```

Спасибо за помощь, коллеги! Всё работает замечательно!